# JavaScript setting up a field for OpportunityCloseDate

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to have the field of OpportunityCloseddate to have date + "30" inserted by javascript when the page is loaded. but its not giving me anything

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Expected Closing Date" for="opportunityCloseDate"/>
    <apex:inputField id="opportunityCloseDate" value="!opportunity.closeDate}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

js
            var now = new Date();
        now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);

```
    var time = $('[id ="opportunityCloseDate"]').val(now);
```

Comment: Is opportunityCloseDate an `apex:inputField` by chance?

Comment: Also, is it being called in DOMContentLoaded or loaded handler, or an inline script?

Comment: @sfdcfox its happening on document ready and Yes it is InputField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce prefixes the id on standard components, so you will need to use the `ends with` selector:

```
$('[id$="opportunityCloseDate"]')
```

I believe it is more efficient to use class selectors:

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="opportunityCloseDate" />
...
$('.opportunityCloseDate');
```

Comment: how can I get the date "12/3/2015' from javascript current time?